# What is the interpretation of the varImp() function

Tags: r, regression, model, importance

Computing the variable importance of different types of models with `varImp(model)`, the obtained results are as follows:

```
                  Overall
                   <dbl>
             A   21752.53           
             B   22032.24
```

I want to obtain the percentage of importance. Must I sum up all relative importance and obtain the percentage associated with each variable? I don't understand the output.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The meaning of `varImp` strongly depends on the model. For linear models, e.g. it is the absolute value of the t statistic. Whether the results actually measure "variable importance" is controversial. You can find the description by invoking the help page with `?varImp`, and the scroll down to the specific model you are using.

Comment: Are you looking for a method that _does_ sum across the variables to the total fit statistic?  Such methods are available for many models.  Also would be helpful to know what model this is based off of and which package the function is from (assuming that it is from `{caret}`).